# angular responsive design - add line breaker when the screen is smaller than some width

Tags: html, css, angular, web, responsive-design

This is my current design when I change the screen width:
[image]

html:

```
<footer class='footer'>
    <div *ngFor='let item of items'>
        <h3 class='footer-item'>{{item.Description}}</h3>
    </div>
</footer>
```

css:

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.footer-item {
    margin: 15px;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to add a line breaker when the screen gets smaller, so the items will go in a new line instead of just making overflow-y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS flex wrap property to wrap items to next line

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```